# Using Asin gem to get Amazon price with shipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I am using asin to find the price of items on Amazon.  I can get the list price, and the lowest new price, but I cannot find the actual price of an item[image].    Does anyone know where I can find this info.

I want the price in green and I can get the prices in red currently.

When I use this code:

```
item.first["item_attributes"]
```

I get this :

```
"item_part_number" => "kah01001",
                     "label" => "Kahootz",
          "legal_disclaimer" => "Small parts are chocking hazards for young childeren     under 4.",
                "list_price" => {
             "amount" => "2499",
      "currency_code" => "USD",
    "formatted_price" => "$24.99"
  },
```

which is the current list price, which is crossed out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which gem you are using, but you can fetch the green price (called the buy box price) using the `GetCompetitivePricingForASIN` call from Amazon's Marketplace Web Services:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetCompetitivePricingForASIN.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a cart.

cart = client.create_cart({:asin => '1430218150', :quantity => 1})

then check the price inside the cart.